# Deploy Flask SocketIO with multiple workers and Redis

Tags: python, flask, redis, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I need to deploy a flask socketio app with multiple workers. For message queuing I am using Redis.
I know that Flask SocketIO is production ready but how can I use workers in it?
are there any other methods?

Comment: Try Flask + Celery + Redis (Celery will provide the workers).

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-multiple-workers) and then ask any specific questions you feel aren't covered.